# How would i scan for other iphone devices

Tags: swift

Hi I want to create a simple app when the app opens for the first time it will show other apple devices in my house that uses Bluetooth and it prints the device name. I am unsure how I can go about this using CoreBluetooth. I have tried a tutorial which i have put down below but it does not show the devices in my house and i have turned on bluetooth. It only shows my neighbour samsung tv. I was also wondering how i would a UUID so that i don't have repeated values in the console. I have even tried lightBlue app and it only show this samsung tv.

[image: Console]

Code

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth


class ViewController: UIViewController,CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    private var centralManager : CBCentralManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)

        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            print("Bluetooth is On")
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        } else {
            print("Bluetooth is not active")
        }
    }
    
 
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("\nName   : \(peripheral.name ?? "(No name)")")
        print("RSSI   : \(RSSI)")
        for ad in advertisementData {
            print("AD Data: \(ad)")
        }
    }
    



}
```

Comment: "I have even tried lightBlue app and it only show this samsung tv." Then that's the only thing advertising. LightBlue is the gold standard here. Phones do not always advertise BLE. There is no reliable way to get all Apple devices in an area. (Note that "Bluetooth" and BLE are not always the same thing. The kind of Bluetooth you use to play music on speakers or headphones is typically not BLE.)

Comment: Okay i want mainly want the bluetooth where you can can connect to a phone for example i have a iphone 5s and iphone se and i want to pair the device but for some reason they do not show on either phones. In my app also i need to use bluetooth to scan for other apple devices e.g. iphones,ipad etc but i'm not sure if i am on the right track.

Comment: What do you mean by "pair" in this case? Typically bluetooth pairing refers to BR/EDR ("Classic") Bluetooth like for audio. That's kind of pairing is not available in iOS. If you just want the devices to communicate with each other, see Apple's sample project that details how to do this. "Transferring Data Between Bluetooth Low Energy Devices" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices  If you're only going to communicate between iPhones, however, you may also want to look at MultipeerConnectivity.

Comment: Yh i want the two devices to connect and when they connect i want to have a textview and the values inputted on both phones will be swapped around, for example name 1 will be on the iphone 5s and name 2 will be on the iphone se. I think MultipeerConnectivity has a limit of 7 devices that can join i will need more than seven.

Comment: "Transferring Data Between Bluetooth Low Energy Devices" (above) covers the tools for that.

Comment: Thanks for you for the help